# Run Node.js server and yarn serve vue-cli app at the same time

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, yarnpkg, vue-cli

I've only start learning vuejs recently and I'm trying to build a real-time messaging apps. I was following this tutorial and able to get the nodejs server running but it would require me to use the command "node myapp.js" every single time and I can't run my vuejs apps after running nodejs server unless i stopped it with ctrl+c and type "yarn serve" again. How do I run the apps and trigger the server at the same time? I would really appreciate suggestions, thanks :)

Comment: Can't you run 2 services in different terminals 

Comment: or you can just "node myapp.js &": that way, your node process will run int he background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try either of these packages:

- [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all)
- [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

Or just open up two console windows

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [Node Foreman](https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman)